# Android advise to sync large amount of data

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I developed a simple Android application to send recorded video via a POST request to a server. 
The "architecture" I though about sounds like this:
After recorded the video, I call a service whose check the connection quality and start uploading videos to the server one by one. 
If something goes bad (timeout or connection is suddenly degraded), I set an alarm manager to try sending again after some minutes, hypotizing connection works again. 
If so, a Broadcast receiver is called, whose calls in the onReceive method the service again. 
when no more video needs to be uploaded, the alarm manager is unset.

I thought to call the service if the alarm manager is not set.

How is this approach?
I know about the Android syncadapter, but I'd like to upload the video as soon as connection becomes available (and good) again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you uploading it on amazon s3 ?

Comment: Still not, we use our server.